# Single Action Gateway

Tags: bpmn

I would like to design a BPMN flow where there is only one single action the user can decide. 
Meaning, in an exclusive gateway there is only one path, say "Done". 
In business point of view, the flow will wait for a User Task. 
When the User finished it task, he/she will say "Done". 
The user have no other actions (This is not a yes/no situation).

So, can I have an exclusive gateway with one condition expression?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a user task is blocking, it will only move forward if the user marks it as completed. So you don't need a gateway after it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to BPMN. I know User Task is blocking. But then how would User mark it completed?

Comment: That is implementation specific. In Intalio|Create, it creates a task record assigned to the user, a role or a group. The user goes to the task queue, clicks on the record, and then marks the task as completed.

Comment: Thanks Antoine...but here is what I am confused...I mean in the BPMN flow diagram how would I show that (if I don't use a Gateway)?

Comment: You should not represent it. In BPMN, user tasks are expected to be blocking.

Comment: When it's waiting for the User Action. There is only one Action User can do here. Say, the action is "Mark Complete". And this is the one and only one action User can do and there is no other option given to the User. This is weird, but that's the requirement given to me.

Answer (score 1):

A (BPMN) gateway is not a *decision* point, as in typical flowcharting. Instead it splits/joins the flow by *evaluating* existing facts established in preceding activities.